# HTML5, Canvas and FireFox

Tags: html, canvas

I have a couple questions about the HTML5-Canvas code shown below.

1. The text does not appear in Firefox 3.6 (it does appear in Chrome.)
2. Regarding the ctx variable (ctx = c.getContext("2d")), should this variable be reused over and over to create additional rectangles, shapes, etc. on the same canvas, or is it desirable to make new context variables for new rectangles, lines, etc.? (It seems to work both ways, but I'm not clear what is standard practice.)

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="350">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = c.getContext("2d"); 


    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";    
    ctx.strokeRect(10,10,180,75);       

    ctx.textBaseline = 'Top';  
    ctx.font         = '20px Sans-Serif';
    ctx.fillStyle    = 'blue';
    ctx.fillText  ("hello", 30, 50);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your call to textBaseline.
In playing with it in JSFiddle, it seems that this is case-sensitive...try making it lower-case:  `ctx.textBaseline = 'top'`

Saved the fiddle link for you: http://jsfiddle.net/NG8Yf/

Comment: That fixed the text issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: a bit of advice as well, use the firebug console for debugging your HTML5 javascript...i found so that it saved me from so many headaches!