# geo chart saving as image or pdf is working in chrome but not in Firefox Browser

Tags: javascript, pdf, html5-canvas, google-visualization

I'm using the Following JavaScript code please some one tell me to improve this
and is it possible to save Whole page as pdf?
Actually the image(image/octet-stream) is coming without any format like *.png or *.jpg 
So please someone improve my code and Suggest some changes so that it'll work on firefox as well.

```
function getImgData(chartContainer) {
              var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
              var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
              var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
              var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
              canvas.setAttribute('width', chartArea.offsetWidth);
              canvas.setAttribute('height', chartArea.offsetHeight);


              canvas.setAttribute(
                  'style',
                  'position: absolute; ' +
                  'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px;' +
                  'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;');
              doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
              canvg(canvas, svg);
              var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
              canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
              return imgData;
          }

          function saveAsImg(chartContainer) {
              var imgData = getImgData(chartContainer);

              // Replacing the mime-type will force the browser to trigger a download
              // rather than displaying the image in the browser window.
              window.location = imgData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
          }

          function toImg(chartContainer, imgContainer) {
              var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
              var img = doc.createElement('img');
              img.src = getImgData(chartContainer);

              while (imgContainer.firstChild) {
                  imgContainer.removeChild(imgContainer.firstChild);
              }
              imgContainer.appendChild(img);
          }
```

And one more think that i'm not using MVC. working on a simple vb.net website

Comment: see this post it may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263640/html5-canvas-and-firefox

Comment: I'm already using in small text, so not helpful